# FFmpeg command line for showing two videos side by side

Tags: console, shell, unix, video

Here is command line for playing two videos side by side in sync in FFmpeg (ffplay). It can be useful for comaring videos, for example.

```
ffplay -v warning -f rawvideo -s 800x400 -i /dev/zero -vf 'movie=video1.mkv,scale=400x400 [mv2] ; movie=video2.mkv,scale=400x400 [mv1]; [in][mv1] overlay=0:0 [tmp]; [tmp][mv2] overlay=400:0'
```

Is there some better way, in particular:

1. Without using fake video input;
2. More easily extendible, without inventing names for `[tmp]`;
3. Maybe with automatic geometry calculation, without manual coordinates;
4. Input video filenames should be more easily visible and together?

Comment: That's really cool! I have to admit I never considered doing that using ffplay. Would you consider using multiple instances of ffplay or vlc or mplayer and align the windows either manually or using -geometry? Or does it all have to be in one window?

Comment: It should pause and seek in sync.

Comment: This question is [being discussed on Meta Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6649/9357).

Answer (score 7):

Partial result

```
ffmpeg -v warning -i video1.mkv -i video2.mkv -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=400:400,pad=800:400 [0:q]; [1:v]scale=400:400[1:q]; [0:q][1:q]overlay=400:0' -f nut -c:v rawvideo -c:a copy - | mplayer -noconsolecontrols -cache-min 1 -cache 1024000 -
```

- Dummy video input removed
- Filenames now separate command line aguments, not parts of a longer string
- Still manual geometry
- Still not automatically extendible to more videos
- Preparing and playing video decoupled, now can use other player instead of `mplayer` (unfortunately `mpv` or `vlc` fails to provide seeking in this scenario)
- Audio is preserved